# Não estou conseguindo extrair um arquivo zip para uma pasta

Tags: c#, arquivo-zip

O código esta a dar este erro:

> A first chance exception of type 'Ionic.Zip.ZipException' occurred in Ionic.Zip.dll
>   Additional information: Cannot read that as a ZipFile
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Código:

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    using Ionic.Zip;
    using System.Net;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                string pastaJogo = @"C:\Game\Play.exe";
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pastaJogo);
                MessageBox.Show("Espere Um Pouco");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            public void AUTOALIZAR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                string fileSave = @"C:\Game\Play.zip";
                string zipFileSave = @"C:\Game\Play.zip";
                string zipFileSaveExtract = @"C:\Game";
                string downloadUrl = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/sq8s2bnyj5fqacv/plsay.zip?dl=1";
                MessageBox.Show("Esta Autoalizando...");
                wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(downloadUrl), fileSave);
                wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(c_DownloadProgress);
                ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(zipFileSave);
                zip.ExtractAll(zipFileSaveExtract);
                wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(c_DownloadFileCompleted);

            } 

            public void c_DownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                int bytesin = int.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
                int totalbyte = int.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
                int kb1 = bytesin / 1024;
                int kb2 = totalbyte / 1024;

                progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                label1.Text = kb1.ToString() + "KB Faltam " + kb2.ToString() + "KB " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
            }

            public void c_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Complete");
            }

            private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não precisa usar `Ionic.Zip` para realizar uma extração. O próprio .NET já possui suporte a isso:

```
        public void AUTOALIZAR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var wc = new WebClient();
            string fileSave = @"C:\Game\Play.zip";
            string zipFileSave = @"C:\Game\Play.zip";
            string zipFileSaveExtract = @"C:\Game";
            string downloadUrl = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/sq8s2bnyj5fqacv/plsay.zip?dl=1";
            MessageBox.Show("Esta Autoalizando...");
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(downloadUrl), fileSave);
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(c_DownloadProgress);

            System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(zipFileSaveExtract, zipFileSave);
            System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFileSaveExtract, zipFileSaveExtract);

            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(c_DownloadFileCompleted);

        }
```

[Você pode ver mais detalhes aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx). [`ZipFile` está em outro namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Outro detalhe é que aparentemente esse código não vai funcionar, porque `DownloadFileAsync` ocorre de forma assíncrona, o que pode fazer a extração ocorrer com um arquivo ainda vazio ou incompleto. No seu lugar, eu moveria o evento de extração do `Click` para o `Completed`, ou seja:

```
        private string fileSave = @"C:\Game\Play.zip";
        private string zipFileSave = @"C:\Game\Play.zip";
        private string zipFileSaveExtract = @"C:\Game";
        private string downloadUrl = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/sq8s2bnyj5fqacv/plsay.zip?dl=1";

        public void AUTOALIZAR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var wc = new WebClient();

            MessageBox.Show("Esta Autoalizando...");
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(downloadUrl), fileSave);
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(c_DownloadProgress);

            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(c_DownloadFileCompleted);

        } 

        public void c_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(zipFileSaveExtract, zipFileSave);
            System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFileSaveExtract, zipFileSaveExtract);

            MessageBox.Show("Complete");
        }
```

Comment: Obrigado ta a funcionar, mas esta a dar um erro e normal? erro: Error    1   The type or namespace name 'ZipFile' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO.Compression' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: [Veja aqui a especificação do `ZipFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Possivelmente faltou algum `using`.